# Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'. how can I rectify this?

Tags: flutter-desktop

Compiler message:
lib/main.dart:10:12: Error: The method 'MainPage' isn't defined for the class 'MyApp'.
 - 'MyApp' is from 'package:demo1/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'MainPage'.
     home: MainPage(
           ^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Comment: add snippets of your code for better understanding of your problem.

Comment: Also run `flutter run --verbose -d <enter-your-device-here>` and see what error it is giving you.